# Colour Counts a range of cell when the date is less than Today() Excel

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, excel-formula

I want to colour count a range of cell when the date is less than TODAY().

The Colour is referenced at the bottom as the red lines

[image]

```
=IF(B9:B372<=TODAY(),ColorCount($B$387,D9:D372),"")
```

I should receive 10 from cells D9:D372

I should receive 3 from cells F9:F372

I should receive 5 from cells H9:H372

CODE

```vb
Function ColorCount(ColorCell As Range, DataRange As Range)

   Dim Data_Range As Range
   Dim Cell_Color As Long

   Cell_Color = ColorCell.Interior.ColorIndex

   For Each Data_Range In DataRange

   If Data_Range.Interior.ColorIndex = Cell_Color Then
   ColorCount = ColorCount + 1
   End If

   Next Data_Range

End Function
```

Comment: The fact that you are not getting `#Name` error indicates that `ColorCount` is a User Defined Function.  Please include that code in your question.  Also indicate how the cells are colored.  Are they conditional formatting or colored by the user manually? It makes a difference.

Comment: Function ColorCount(ColorCell As Range, DataRange As Range)

   Dim Data_Range As Range
   Dim Cell_Color As Long

   Cell_Color = ColorCell.Interior.ColorIndex

   For Each Data_Range In DataRange

   If Data_Range.Interior.ColorIndex = Cell_Color Then
   ColorCount = ColorCount + 1
   End If

   Next Data_Range

End Function

Comment: User manually copy and pastes from colour at the bottom. Defined on cell B387

Comment: If you need to add code please *edit your question* and add it there.  https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75162566/edit

Comment: Aren't you missing a `SUM()` in that formula?

Comment: Added code to question. Thanks

Comment: The code will check all cells - also those > today. Is tha what you want?

Comment: Tim, cell reference E3 is the ColorCount function working where I total the colour count from cells E9:E387. It's when I come to the If Statement where I need to colour count less than TODAY(). IF coming up with Volatile

Comment: Ike, I need the function to only count the cells which are coloured up until TODAY() 18th Jan. Do I need to set-up a new module?

Answer (score 0):

This will return both results - either until today, if `FilterDataRange` which is in your case from column B, is provided - or all colored cells:

```vb
Function ColorCount(ColorCell As Range, DataRange As Range, _
    Optional FilterDataRange As Range)

   Dim Data_Range As Range
   Dim Cell_Color As Long

   Cell_Color = ColorCell.Interior.ColorIndex


   For Each Data_Range In DataRange
        If Data_Range.Interior.ColorIndex = Cell_Color Then
            If Not FilterDataRange Is Nothing Then
                If FilterDataRange.Cells(Data_Range.Row) <= Date Then
                    ColorCount = ColorCount + 1
                End If
            Else
                ColorCount = ColorCount + 1
            End If
        End If

   Next Data_Range

End Function
```

But this won't be recalculated if the color of a cell changes ...

I would work with e.g. an `v` for vacation - and then apply conditional formatting. Then you can use a normal formula to count the `v`s in the column